# IFNULL() Still returning Null - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query that groups together some dates working out counts of of rows.. I am using a left join to join the two tables together and were rows in the second column are NULL I want to output 0.

Here is a snippet of my data.

**TRANSACTIONS TABLE**

```
ITEM    DOE                  T_DOEDAY
42      11/06/2015 10:40    11/06/2015
14      12/06/2015 06:19    12/06/2015
2151    15/06/2015 07:27    15/06/2015
2114    16/06/2015 09:58    16/06/2015
98541   17/06/2015 07:15    17/06/2015
101     18/06/2015 10:14    18/06/2015
9854    19/06/2015 06:14    19/06/2015
2121    22/06/2015 07:14    22/06/2015
2354    23/06/2015 07:12    23/06/2015
252     24/06/2015 07:12    24/06/2015
5654    15/06/2015 10:12    25/06/2015
245     15/06/2015 09:11    26/06/2015
..............
```

**ATTRIBUTES TABLE**

```
ITEM        DOE                 DOEDAY
CD      11/06/2015 10:40        11/06/2015
CD      12/06/2015 06:19        12/06/2015
OP      15/06/2015 07:27        15/06/2015
DF      16/06/2015 09:58        16/06/2015
CD      19/06/2015 06:14        19/06/2015
CD      22/06/2015 07:14        22/06/2015
OD      23/06/2015 07:12        23/06/2015
OD      24/06/2015 07:12        24/06/2015
OD      15/06/2015 10:12        25/06/2015
CD      15/06/2015 09:11        26/06/2015
...............
```

I have tried the following in my query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ITEM) AS ITEM_COUNT, T.ITEM, T.DOE, T.DOEDAY AS T_DOEDAY, T.pos 
      FROM TRANSACTIONS T 
      group by T_DOEDAY ) J1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(T1.DEFECT), 0) as DEFECT_COUNT, 
            T1.DOEDAY AS T1_DOEDAY 
     FROM ATTRIBUTES T1  
     GROUP BY T1_DOEDAY ) J2 
ON T_DOEDAY = T1_DOEDAY
```

Which outputs the following -

```
ITEM_COUNT ITEM DOE                     T_DOEDAY  DEFECT_COUNT      T1_DOEDAY
32      10      11/06/2015 10:40        11/06/2015      0       11/06/2015
69      18      12/06/2015 06:19        12/06/2015      0       12/06/2015
49      2       15/06/2015 07:27        15/06/2015      0       15/06/2015
14      21      16/06/2015 09:58        16/06/2015      0       16/06/2015
3       6       17/06/2015 07:14        17/06/2015      NULL        NULL
16      18      18/06/2015 09:18        18/06/2015      NULL        NULL
31      22      19/06/2015 06:14        19/06/2015      0       19/06/2015
98      89      22/06/2015 07:14        22/06/2015      0       22/06/2015
14      204     23/06/2015 07:12        23/06/2015      0       23/06/2015
68      202     24/06/2015 07:12        24/06/2015      0       24/06/2015
26      8       15/06/2015 10:12        25/06/2015      0       25/06/2015
133     1       15/06/2015 09:11        26/06/2015      0       26/06/2015
```

So i tried this query-

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ITEM) AS ITEM_COUNT, T.ITEM, T.DOE, T.DOEDAY AS T_DOEDAY, T.pos 
      FROM TRANSACTIONS T group by T_DOEDAY ) J1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(T1.DEFECT) = NULL,0,COUNT(T1.DEFECT)) as DEFECT_COUNT, 
        T1.DOEDAY AS T1_DOEDAY 
     FROM ATTRIBUTES T1  
    GROUP BY T1_DOEDAY ) J2 
ON T_DOEDAY = T1_DOEDAY
```

Which outputs the following again -

```
ITEM_COUNT ITEM DOE                     T_DOEDAY  DEFECT_COUNT      T1_DOEDAY
32      10      11/06/2015 10:40        11/06/2015      0       11/06/2015
69      18      12/06/2015 06:19        12/06/2015      0       12/06/2015
49      2       15/06/2015 07:27        15/06/2015      0       15/06/2015
14      21      16/06/2015 09:58        16/06/2015      0       16/06/2015
3       6       17/06/2015 07:14        17/06/2015      NULL        NULL
16      18      18/06/2015 09:18        18/06/2015      NULL        NULL
31      22      19/06/2015 06:14        19/06/2015      0       19/06/2015
98      89      22/06/2015 07:14        22/06/2015      0       22/06/2015
14      204     23/06/2015 07:12        23/06/2015      0       23/06/2015
68      202     24/06/2015 07:12        24/06/2015      0       24/06/2015
26      8       15/06/2015 10:12        25/06/2015      0       25/06/2015
133     1       15/06/2015 09:11        26/06/2015      0       26/06/2015
```

**Expected Result**

```
ITEM_COUNT ITEM DOE                     T_DOEDAY  DEFECT_COUNT      T1_DOEDAY
32      10      11/06/2015 10:40        11/06/2015      0       11/06/2015
69      18      12/06/2015 06:19        12/06/2015      0       12/06/2015
49      2       15/06/2015 07:27        15/06/2015      0       15/06/2015
14      21      16/06/2015 09:58        16/06/2015      0       16/06/2015
3       6       17/06/2015 07:14        17/06/2015      0        NULL
16      18      18/06/2015 09:18        18/06/2015      0        NULL
31      22      19/06/2015 06:14        19/06/2015      0       19/06/2015
98      89      22/06/2015 07:14        22/06/2015      0       22/06/2015
14      204     23/06/2015 07:12        23/06/2015      0       23/06/2015
68      202     24/06/2015 07:12        24/06/2015      0       24/06/2015
26      8       15/06/2015 10:12        25/06/2015      0       25/06/2015
133     1       15/06/2015 09:11        26/06/2015      0       26/06/2015
```

I don't understand why the IFNULL or IF functions aren't working as they should, the sql runs fine, no errors are flagged up..

If anyone could shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Sorry, Just edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `IFNULL` after joining, not in the subquery that does the counting. The nulls are added by the `LEFT JOIN` when there are no matching rows.

```
SELECT J1.*, IFNULL(defect_count, 0) AS defect_count
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ITEM) AS ITEM_COUNT, T.ITEM, T.DOE, T.DOEDAY AS T_DOEDAY, T.pos 
      FROM TRANSACTIONS T 
      group by T_DOEDAY ) J1 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as DEFECT_COUNT, 
            T1.DOEDAY AS T1_DOEDAY 
     FROM ATTRIBUTES T1  
     GROUP BY T1_DOEDAY ) J2 
ON J1.T_DOEDAY = J2.T1_DOEDAY
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a default value if `isnull` is true

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ITEM) AS ITEM_COUNT, T.ITEM, T.DOE, T.DOEDAY AS T_DOEDAY, T.pos FROM TRANSACTIONS T group by T_DOEDAY ) J1 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(T1.DEFECT),0) as DEFECT_COUNT, 
     T1.DOEDAY AS T1_DOEDAY FROM ATTRIBUTES T1  GROUP BY T1_DOEDAY ) J2 ON T_DOEDAY = T1_DOE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using `IFNULL` try the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ITEM) AS ITEM_COUNT, T.ITEM, T.DOE, T.DOEDAY AS T_DOEDAY, T.pos FROM TRANSACTIONS T group by T_DOEDAY ) J1 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(T1.DEFECT),0) as DEFECT_COUNT, 
     T1.DOEDAY AS T1_DOEDAY FROM ATTRIBUTES T1  GROUP BY T1_DOEDAY ) J2 ON T_DOEDAY = T1_DOE
```

[NULL Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Comment: I am using IFNULL, sorry about my typo.. just edited the question.